# Cancel Revoke developer certificate from my account

Tags: iphone, certificate

I am a new iPhone developer. By mistake I Have revoked my developer certificate. How can I renew it?

Comment: Make a new one.  You can't unrevoke a developer certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a certificate in revoked, you have no other option but to generate a new one. You can't "renew" a revoked certificate.